# Как обнулить String::from в Rust?

Tags: строки, rust

Допустим, у меня есть переменная:

```rust
let mut test = String:from("какой-то текст");
```

Как мне этот текст стереть и сделать следующее?

```rust
test.push_str("другой текст");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. набираем в гугле что-то вроде "rust string"
2. переходим по ссылке https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html
3. внимательно смотрим все методы в поисках подходящего
4. находим метод [`clear`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clear):

```rust
test.clear()
```